# geting error in specifying class path when running program from cmd

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to run program from command prompt

Here is my director structure

[image: directory structure]

In the classes directory i have this structure

[image: Classes Directory]

In the email folder i have two properties file `general-mail-settings.properties` and `customer-mail-settings.properties`

Now when i run the command

```
D:\vintnes\lasses>java -cp ".;..\dependency-jars\*"  com/softech/ls360/integration/BatchImport vintners
```

Then i get the error that

```
java.lang.Exception: Email Properties File not found: src\main\resources\email\general-mail-settings.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at 
...
```

I tried this to specify path

```
java -cp ".;..\dependency-jars\*;.\email\*.*"  com/softech/ls360/integration/BatchImport customer
```

But still i am getting the error. I tried `;email\*` and `\email\*`, but still i am getting the error. How can i specify path so program get run?

Thanks

Comment: You specific directories and JARs in class pathes, not individual resources as such.  If you want to include a resource, add the base directory for the file. Your error message suggest it is looking for `src\main\resources\email\general-mail-settings.properties` relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You put a path to `src/main/resources` in your code somewhere. This is a directory used by Maven builds to hold "resource" files (files that aren't code but that should be copied into the finished artifact, like configuration files or media). The contents of `src/main/resources` are copied directly into the root of the artifact as-is, so in this case, the `email` directory is copied straight into your `classes` directory.  Remove the `src/main/resources` part of the path from your properties lookup.

Comment: In the code i am doing something like this `ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("email/general-mail-settings");` By default maven uses `src/main/recources/` so i just specify `email/general-mail-settings`. Now what should i do ?